# C# Console changes the colors of previous commands/outputs

Tags: c#, windows, terminal, colors, console

It is difficult to find a suitable title for this question, I try to describe my problem as best as I can.

In my command line program I use the library [ColorfulConsole](http://colorfulconsole.com/) (mainly because of StyleSheets). Everything works very well, all my colors are displayed correctly.

The problem occurs when I run another command in the same console session, the colors are displayed correctly, but the colors of the previous output are overwritten as well. This causes error messages to have the same color as debug output.

Lets say i run `program.exe init -p <unknown directory>`. I get the following (correct) output:

[image: command failed]

*The execution time is different from the others, that was my fault, but has nothing to do with the problem*

`program.exe init -p <known directory>`

[image: command failed successfully?]

[image: command executed successfully]

**Question A**: Is it even possible to keep the colors of previous commands without overwriting them?

**Question B**: Have I missed something fundamental?

I already tried to:

1. Run `Colorful.Console.ReplaceAllColorsWithDefaults();` after program execution
2. Run `Console.ResetColor();` after program execution
3. Run `Console.Clear();` after program execution (kinda works, but clearing the console after each command is not that great)
4. Find a related issue [issue](https://github.com/tomakita/Colorful.Console/issues)
5. Find something related on SO

I know the Windows console has a color limit, but I haven't exceeded it so I don't think it has anything to do with this. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT (minimal reproducible example using Colorful.Console @ 1.2.10)**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using Console = Colorful.Console;

namespace MinimalReproducibleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Compiled with Color.Firebrick", Color.Firebrick);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this program the text is displayed in the color firebrick:

[image: with firebrick]

if i recompile the program with a different color and execute it:

[image: with coral]

Comment: 1) I'm not sure I see the problem, where do "previous" messages become overwritten? 2) I guess we also need to see the actual code or - even better - a [mcve] to help you.

Comment: The Windows console supports a fixed size palette of colors. If you change entries in that palette, you're also changing all output that previously used the same slot in the palette.